# Can software cause the home button to stop working on iOS?

Tags: ios, hardware, performance

I have a new (2 months) iPhone 5 and it just froze in the "settings" app. Everything on the phone is controlled with the round button at the bottom, when I press it nothing happens anymore.

Can this be a software problem?

Comment: I suggest you include more details. When did this start happening? What have you tried to do?

Comment: Did you try to restart it by pressing the Power button (at the top right of the phone) for >10s?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a [Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1430) describing ways to reset/restart an iPhone:

> **Restarting your device**
>
> - Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button for a few seconds until the red "slide to power off" slider appears, and then slide the slider.
> - Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the Apple logo appears.
>
> **Resetting your device**
>
> Note: Reset your device only if you are unable to restart it.
>
> - Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button and the Home button together for at least ten seconds, until the Apple logo appears.